# How to add Header/Custom View to JSQMessagesViewController?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, jsqmessagesviewcontroller

I'm using a storyboard to build my UIs. I wasn't able to find same ticket with same question on JSQMessageViewController's repo on Github.

Basically, I want to add a custom view, say a header in my controller, like so:

[image]

What I did so far:

1. Add the view to the storyboard - didn't work.
2. I programmatically made a `UICollectionReusableView` and add it to the data source function: `viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind`

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

You can change anything you like but here is how to do it very simply programatically.

call `addViewOnTop()` this in your `viewDidLoad`

```
func addViewOnTop() {
    let selectableView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 60, width: self.view.bounds.width, height: 40))
    selectableView.backgroundColor = .red
    let randomViewLabel = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 20, y: 10, width: 100, height: 16))
    randomViewLabel.text = "RandomView"
    selectableView.addSubview(randomViewLabel)
    view.addSubview(selectableView)
}
```

Add an UIEdgeInset to let you view your messages under the new view
Call this in the `viewDidLoad()`

```
 self.collectionView?.collectionViewLayout.sectionInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 80, left: 0, bottom: 0, right: 0)
```

Comment: that will just add a view to the chat but it won't adjust the insets of the messages.